# redirect non-www to www page but it is becaming a normal url?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, friendly-url

I have this htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)/?$ category.php?categoria=$1&id=1 [L,QSA,NC]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

if someone types mysite.com it will redirect to **www**.mysite.com

the problem is, I have a page called `category`:

> www.mysite.com/category/animals

if an user types without the www it will redirect to www, but the url will be:

> www.mysite.com/category.php?categoria=animals&id=1

and I want it to redirect to category/animals not the full url (category.php?categoria=animals&id=1)...
what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rewriting to use `$1`, simply redirect back using `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: still the same thing ;/ when I remove the www it will become www...category.php?categoria=animals&id=1

Comment: @RickJoe Clear your browser's cache. Also, if there are any other rewrite rules, the above rules should appear first in the whole file/list.

Comment: oh, it works now! it was on the end of my htaccess... that is why it was not working! thank you very much, friend!